Full join - bash
I have two tsv files. The first contains a list of airport codes combined with a year. The second the average daily landings of different types of aircraft.
I would like to create a third file that joins the data from the two files even if there is no match between the data in file1 with data in file2. The equivalent of an sql full outer join as I understand it.
The unpopulated cells of the combined output should be blank.
file1 - abbrvtd.tsv
Abbrvtd
LAM1999
LAM1998
LAM1997
LAM1996
LAM1995
LAM1994
TAW1999
TAW1998
TAW1997
TAW1996
TAW1995
TAW1994
DRN1999
DRN1998
DRN1997
DRN1996
DRN1995
DRN1994

file2 - landings.tsv
Abbrvtd Airport Codes   Year    Commercial  Passenger   Private Helicopter
LAM1999 LAM 1999    71.8    59.4    65.2    40.7
LAM1998 LAM 1998    71.8    58.8    64.7    40.5
LAM1997 LAM 1997    71.6    58.3    64.1    40.5
LAM1994 LAM 1994    70.8    55.8    63.1    70.8
TAW1999 TAW 1999    40.7    62.4    71.4    65.2
TAW1997 TAW 1997    40.5    60.9    70.8    64.1
TAW1996 TAW 1996    40.2    60.4    70.4    63.7
TAW1995 TAW 1995    40.2    59.9    70.3    60.9
TAW1994 TAW 1994    39.9    59.1    70.2    60.4
DRN1999 DRN 1999    39.7    58.7    40.5    59.9
DRN1994 DRN 1994    30.2    55.8    59.9    39.6

output desired:
Abbrvtd Airport Codes   Year    Commercial  Passenger   Private Helicopter
LAM1999 LAM 1999    71.8    59.4    65.2    40.7
LAM1998 LAM 1998    71.8    58.8    64.7    40.5
LAM1997 LAM 1997    71.6    58.3    64.1    40.5
LAM1996                     
LAM1995                     
LAM1994 LAM 1994    70.8    55.8    63.1    70.8
TAW1999 TAW 1999    40.7    62.4    71.4    65.2
TAW1998                     
TAW1997 TAW 1997    40.5    60.9    70.8    64.1
TAW1996 TAW 1996    40.2    60.4    70.4    63.7
TAW1995 TAW 1995    40.2    59.9    70.3    60.9
TAW1994 TAW 1994    39.9    59.1    70.2    60.4
DRN1999 DRN 1999    39.7    58.7    40.5    59.9
DRN1998                     
DRN1997                     
DRN1996                     
DRN1995                     
DRN1994 DRN 1994    30.2    55.8    59.9    39.6

The closest I've come is with the code below. but it returns an output that looks like file2-landings.tsv
I have tried using various iterations of awk and now trying with join:
join -a 1 -a 2 -e NULL -t$"\t" -1 1 -2 1 -o 2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7 abbrvtd.tsv landings.tsv

Thank you.
RESOLVED - @EdMorton solution generates the required output

I formatted this one for you but for future questions please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and then format your sample input, expected output, and code as Code Blocks.

Is your first column REALLY named Abbrvtd in abbrvtd.tsv but Abbrvted (extra e) in landings.tsv and, if so, do you really want that output first column name to be the name from abbrvtd.tsv rather than from landings.tsv? It's not hard to do, just adds a bit of complexity I suspect you don't really need.

@EdMorton Thank you for the solution. Works great. The extra e was a typo. Apologies. Didn't intend to complicate the request. Advice re: formatting noted. Thanks again

join requires sorted input but your input isn't sorted so at a minimum you'd need to add that step before using join on it. You could do something like this:
$ { head -n 1 landings.tsv;
    join -t $'\t' -a 1 -a 2 -j 1 \
        <(tail -n +2 abbrvtd.tsv | sort) \
        <(tail -n +2 landings.tsv | sort);
  }

but then you'd still need to pad the lines from abbrvtd.tsv with tabs to create empty fields so you end up with:
$ { head -n 1 landings.tsv;
    join -t $'\t' -a 1 -a 2 -j 1 \
        <(tail -n +2 abbrvtd.tsv | sort) \
        <(tail -n +2 landings.tsv | sort);
  } | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==1{nf=NF} {$nf=$nf} 1'
Abbrvted        Airport Codes   Year    Commercial      Passenger       Private Helicopter
DRN1994 DRN     1994    30.2    55.8    59.9    39.6
DRN1995
DRN1996
DRN1997
DRN1998
DRN1999 DRN     1999    39.7    58.7    40.5    59.9
LAM1994 LAM     1994    70.8    55.8    63.1    70.8
LAM1995
LAM1996
LAM1997 LAM     1997    71.6    58.3    64.1    40.5
LAM1998 LAM     1998    71.8    58.8    64.7    40.5
LAM1999 LAM     1999    71.8    59.4    65.2    40.7
TAW1994 TAW     1994    39.9    59.1    70.2    60.4
TAW1995 TAW     1995    40.2    59.9    70.3    60.9
TAW1996 TAW     1996    40.2    60.4    70.4    63.7
TAW1997 TAW     1997    40.5    60.9    70.8    64.1
TAW1998
TAW1999 TAW     1999    40.7    62.4    71.4    65.2

Alternatively, using any awk, sort, and cut and the Decorate-Sort-Undecorate idiom:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
    NR == FNR {
        if ( FNR == 1 ) {
            print 1, $0
            nf = NF
        }
        else {
            vals[$1] = $0
        }
        next
    }
    FNR > 1 {
        if ( $1 in vals ) {
            $0 = vals[$1]
            delete vals[$1]
        }
        $nf = $nf
        print 2, $0
    }
    END {
        for ( key in vals ) {
            print 2, vals[key]
        }
    }
' landings.tsv abbrvtd.tsv |
sort -k1,1n -k2 |
cut -f 2-


$ ./tst.sh
Abbrvted        Airport Codes   Year    Commercial      Passenger       Private Helicopter
DRN1994 DRN     1994    30.2    55.8    59.9    39.6
DRN1995
DRN1996
DRN1997
DRN1998
DRN1999 DRN     1999    39.7    58.7    40.5    59.9
LAM1994 LAM     1994    70.8    55.8    63.1    70.8
LAM1995
LAM1996
LAM1997 LAM     1997    71.6    58.3    64.1    40.5
LAM1998 LAM     1998    71.8    58.8    64.7    40.5
LAM1999 LAM     1999    71.8    59.4    65.2    40.7
TAW1994 TAW     1994    39.9    59.1    70.2    60.4
TAW1995 TAW     1995    40.2    59.9    70.3    60.9
TAW1996 TAW     1996    40.2    60.4    70.4    63.7
TAW1997 TAW     1997    40.5    60.9    70.8    64.1
TAW1998
TAW1999 TAW     1999    40.7    62.4    71.4    65.2

So you can see that the added lines from abbrvtd.tsv now have the same number of tab-separated fields as the landings.tsv file did:
$ ./tst.sh | cat -t
Abbrvted^IAirport Codes^IYear^ICommercial^IPassenger^IPrivate^IHelicopter
DRN1994^IDRN^I1994^I30.2^I55.8^I59.9^I39.6
DRN1995^I^I^I^I^I^I
DRN1996^I^I^I^I^I^I
DRN1997^I^I^I^I^I^I
DRN1998^I^I^I^I^I^I
DRN1999^IDRN^I1999^I39.7^I58.7^I40.5^I59.9
LAM1994^ILAM^I1994^I70.8^I55.8^I63.1^I70.8
LAM1995^I^I^I^I^I^I
LAM1996^I^I^I^I^I^I
LAM1997^ILAM^I1997^I71.6^I58.3^I64.1^I40.5
LAM1998^ILAM^I1998^I71.8^I58.8^I64.7^I40.5
LAM1999^ILAM^I1999^I71.8^I59.4^I65.2^I40.7
TAW1994^ITAW^I1994^I39.9^I59.1^I70.2^I60.4
TAW1995^ITAW^I1995^I40.2^I59.9^I70.3^I60.9
TAW1996^ITAW^I1996^I40.2^I60.4^I70.4^I63.7
TAW1997^ITAW^I1997^I40.5^I60.9^I70.8^I64.1
TAW1998^I^I^I^I^I^I
TAW1999^ITAW^I1999^I40.7^I62.4^I71.4^I65.2


Aside: If you really did have a different first column name in each file and needed the name from abbrvtd.tsv in the output as shown in the original version of the example in your question then you could do this:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
    NR == FNR {
        if ( FNR == 1 ) {
            hdr = $0
            nf = NF
        }
        else {
            vals[$1] = $0
        }
        next
    }
    {
        if ( FNR == 1 ) {
            key = $1
            $0 = hdr
            $1 = key
        }
        else if ( $1 in vals ) {
            $0 = vals[$1]
            delete vals[$1]
        }
        $nf = $nf
        print (FNR > 1), $0
    }
    END {
        for ( key in vals ) {
            print 2, vals[key]
        }
    }
' landings.tsv abbrvtd.tsv |
sort -k1,1n -k2 |
cut -f 2-


$ ./tst.sh
Abbrvtd Airport Codes   Year    Commercial      Passenger       Private Helicopter
DRN1994 DRN     1994    30.2    55.8    59.9    39.6
DRN1995
DRN1996
DRN1997
DRN1998
DRN1999 DRN     1999    39.7    58.7    40.5    59.9
LAM1994 LAM     1994    70.8    55.8    63.1    70.8
LAM1995
LAM1996
LAM1997 LAM     1997    71.6    58.3    64.1    40.5
LAM1998 LAM     1998    71.8    58.8    64.7    40.5
LAM1999 LAM     1999    71.8    59.4    65.2    40.7
TAW1994 TAW     1994    39.9    59.1    70.2    60.4
TAW1995 TAW     1995    40.2    59.9    70.3    60.9
TAW1996 TAW     1996    40.2    60.4    70.4    63.7
TAW1997 TAW     1997    40.5    60.9    70.8    64.1
TAW1998
TAW1999 TAW     1999    40.7    62.4    71.4    65.2


As you slapped linux tag at your question I suggest trying csvkit if you are allowed to install tools. It does comes with csvjoin command

Merges two or more CSV tables together using a method analogous to SQL
JOIN operation. By default it performs an inner join, but full outer,
left outer, and right outer are also available via flags.

Simple example let file1.tsv content be
LETTER  PHONETIC
A   ABLE
C   CHARLIE

and file2.tsv content be
LETTER  NUMBER
A   1
B   2

then
csvjoin -d $'\t' --columns "LETTER" --outer file1.tsv file2.tsv

gives output
LETTER,PHONETIC,LETTER2,NUMBER
A,ABLE,A,1
C,CHARLIE,,
,,B,2

Explanation: I inform csvjoin that tab is delimiter and it should do OUTER JOIN at column named LETTER.
(tested in csvjoin 1.4.0)
EDIT: as suggested in comments I am adding example with input based on question. For brevity sake I shortened some columns names in 2nd file, let abbrvtd.tsv content be
Abbrvtd
LAM1999
LAM1998
LAM1997
LAM1996
LAM1995
LAM1994
TAW1999
TAW1998
TAW1997
TAW1996
TAW1995
TAW1994
DRN1999
DRN1998
DRN1997
DRN1996
DRN1995
DRN1994

and landings.tsv content be
Abbrvtd Airport Year    Comm    Pass    Priv    Heli
LAM1999 LAM 1999    71.8    59.4    65.2    40.7
LAM1998 LAM 1998    71.8    58.8    64.7    40.5
LAM1997 LAM 1997    71.6    58.3    64.1    40.5
LAM1994 LAM 1994    70.8    55.8    63.1    70.8
TAW1999 TAW 1999    40.7    62.4    71.4    65.2
TAW1997 TAW 1997    40.5    60.9    70.8    64.1
TAW1996 TAW 1996    40.2    60.4    70.4    63.7
TAW1995 TAW 1995    40.2    59.9    70.3    60.9
TAW1994 TAW 1994    39.9    59.1    70.2    60.4
DRN1999 DRN 1999    39.7    58.7    40.5    59.9
DRN1994 DRN 1994    30.2    55.8    59.9    39.6

then
csvjoin -d $'\t' --columns "Abbrvtd" --outer abbrvtd.tsv landings.tsv

gives output
Abbrvtd,Abbrvtd2,Airport,Year,Comm,Pass,Priv,Heli
LAM1999,LAM1999,LAM,1999,71.8,59.4,65.2,40.7
LAM1998,LAM1998,LAM,1998,71.8,58.8,64.7,40.5
LAM1997,LAM1997,LAM,1997,71.6,58.3,64.1,40.5
LAM1996,,,,,,,
LAM1995,,,,,,,
LAM1994,LAM1994,LAM,1994,70.8,55.8,63.1,70.8
TAW1999,TAW1999,TAW,1999,40.7,62.4,71.4,65.2
TAW1998,,,,,,,
TAW1997,TAW1997,TAW,1997,40.5,60.9,70.8,64.1
TAW1996,TAW1996,TAW,1996,40.2,60.4,70.4,63.7
TAW1995,TAW1995,TAW,1995,40.2,59.9,70.3,60.9
TAW1994,TAW1994,TAW,1994,39.9,59.1,70.2,60.4
DRN1999,DRN1999,DRN,1999,39.7,58.7,40.5,59.9
DRN1998,,,,,,,
DRN1997,,,,,,,
DRN1996,,,,,,,
DRN1995,,,,,,,
DRN1994,DRN1994,DRN,1994,30.2,55.8,59.9,39.6


Does csvjoin require the input to be sorted, same as join does? It doesn't say in the man page you referenced and I don't have it available to test with.

@EdMorton there is no need to be sorted, if I would change 1st line with 2nd line in file1.tsv this would result in changing 1st line with 2nd line in output.

OK, thanks. And is there any option for it to merge the 2 LETTER columns instead of outputing a separate LETTER column per input file? Also, does it produce output where all lines have the same number of fields or different numbers per input file? I'd be very interested to see it's output when run on the OPs example in the question, would you mind adding that and piping the output to cat -t or similar so we can see where the tabs are? I'm surprised to notice now that your output is comma-separated despite the input being tab-separated, is there a way to make it use the same separator?

The whole point of awk is to avoid any amount of pre-sorting :

awk 'FNR < NR ? (($++NF  =  __[$!_]_) ||
                   --NF) : (__[$!_] = $+_)<_' FS='\t' OFS='\t'

    <( printf '%s' "$testfile2" | gsed -zE 's/ [ ]+/\t/g' ) 
    <( printf '%s' "$testfile1" )


Abbrvtd Abbrvtd Airport Codes Year Commercial Passenger  Private  Helicopter
LAM1999   LAM1999   LAM   1999   71.8   59.4   65.2   40.7
LAM1998   LAM1998   LAM   1998   71.8   58.8   64.7   40.5
LAM1997   LAM1997   LAM   1997   71.6   58.3   64.1   40.5
LAM1996   
LAM1995   
LAM1994   LAM1994   LAM   1994   70.8   55.8   63.1   70.8
TAW1999   TAW1999   TAW   1999   40.7   62.4   71.4   65.2
TAW1998   
TAW1997   TAW1997   TAW   1997   40.5   60.9   70.8   64.1
TAW1996   TAW1996   TAW   1996   40.2   60.4   70.4   63.7
TAW1995   TAW1995   TAW   1995   40.2   59.9   70.3   60.9
TAW1994   TAW1994   TAW   1994   39.9   59.1   70.2   60.4
DRN1999   DRN1999   DRN   1999   39.7   58.7   40.5   59.9
DRN1998   
DRN1997   
DRN1996   
DRN1995   
DRN1994   DRN1994   DRN   1994   30.2   55.8   59.9   39.6

